# Cache collection object

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a collection that holding a large amount of data that retrieve from DB.

```
public class Item
{

    private string name_;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name_; }
        set { name_ = value; }
    }    

    ....
}
```

This set of data will be frequently use by the user. 
Is there any way I can cache this collection after retrieve from DB and reuse in other page?

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to cache data from page to page in ASP.NET
You can user session , but not always recommended.
You can transfer the data via [page Items](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/558778/Pages-Items-Property) 
But usually SQL server cache most common data using its own engine. So when you pull data from SQL the second time this data will be already cached. Depending on the common use of this data.